# Windows Registry Shell Extension - Passing one file through multiple commands

Tags: shell, cmd, registry

**I'm not a C/C# programmer, so I can't develop a clear solution myself.**

I have a simple registry shell extension here - my target is to use **2** utils one file - I thought that using the `&&` symbol which means *`continue if successful`* would be solution, but it wasn't.

Console pop-ups for split second, returning nothing. However, when I copy-paste the command in the `cmd.exe` and replace `%1` with file path, everything works smoothly.

How it works?

---

```bash
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Optimizers]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\ContextMenus\Optimizers]

; --- ;

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Optimizers]
@="Optimizers"
"Icon"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\WMPLoc.dll,-102"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="*\\ContextMenus\\Optimizers"
"AppliesTo"="System.FileExtension:=.png"

; --- ;

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\ContextMenus\Optimizers\Shell\01_PNG]
@="Optimize PNG"
"Icon"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\ImageRes.dll,-168"
"AppliesTo"="System.FileExtension:=.png"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\ContextMenus\Optimizers\Shell\01_PNG\command]
@="E:\\pngquant.exe 256 --ext .png -f -s 1 --skip-if-larger --nofs \"%1\" && E:\\oxipng.exe \"%1\" -a -i 1 -o max -p --strip all"
```

Comment: Not sure if `&&` and other CMD.EXE syntax is supported at this point. In fact it would be strange if the shell uses `CMD.EXE` to run those command lines (it might have special handling for running .cmd/.bat though as this seems to work). You could try putting the command line from the reg file into a dedicated batch file. Then calls this from the reg file.

Comment: I can use `cmd.exe /c ...` but it's just ugly :P

Comment: Ugly or broken - the choice is yours ;-)